# How to save image in Silverlight

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight

Hi I have created a Silverlight application that allows the user to type their name, select date and sign their name, (a signature strip). I am looking to add to a webform I have already created. I build the signature strip using the borderInk and inkP tool in silverlight on a grid. However i don't know how to save the image. I want to store it in a database, I have already created. I also want to attach the silverlight application the the webforms I have created. Any help on how to do this??

Answer (score 0):

You should use WCF service and save the image in server using Bytes Stream.

Here is an example,

[Upload image in silverlight WCF](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-SaveFileDialog-in-Silverlight-3.aspx)

Comment: Your link goes to a 404.

Answer (score 0):

You should render your drawing surface element (Grid) to the Bitmap and save the result.

The sample method which should get an element and return bytes of the jpeg image

```
private byte[] RenderToJpeg(FrameworkElement element)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(element, null);
        bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 90);

        stream.Flush();
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: WriteableBitmap doesn't have a SaveJpeg method in Silverlight 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving image using `OpenFileDialog`,this could helps you.

```
 decimal _imagementSize = 0;
 string _imageName = "";
 string _imageType = "";
 Binary _image;
 OpenFileDialog dialog=new OpenFileDialog();

 private void btnSaveImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   dialog.Multiselect = false;
   dialog.Filter = "All Files | *.*";
   if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
   {
       bool fileExist = dialog.File.Exists;
       if (fileExist)
       {       
          UploadFile();    
       }                  
   }
 }

 private void UploadFile()
 {
    double fileLength = 0;
    var stream = dialog.File.OpenRead();
    var bnr = new BinaryReader(stream);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length + 1];
    buffer = bnr.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
    fileLength = stream.Length;
    _imageName = dialog.File.Name;
    _imageType = dialog.File.Extension;
    _imageSize = (decimal)(fileLength / 1024);
    _image = new Binary() { Bytes = buffer };         
 }
```

and if you are using `WCF service` to save image,you just send _image

and `WCF method` like

```
[OperationContract]
public void SaveImage(System.Data.Linq.Binary _image)
{
   //save image to DB or enything
}
```